# ページの読み込みが終わらない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

RoRを使ってwebページを作っています。
　ページの読み込みが終わらなくなりました。ページは表示されるのですが、ブラウザの読み込み中を表す回転マークが残ります。
　これはどういう原因で起こる事象ですか？

私はプログラミングを初めて3か月程度ですが、今まではJavaScriptに誤りがあるときに生じるものだと思っていました。今回は、心当たりのあるJavaScriptを空にしても変化がありませんでした。

今回の経緯は、次のようになります。チャットを作ろうとしていて、外観が大体できました。この時は、ページの読み込みは終わりました。送受信部分にとりかかろうとして、ActionCntroller::live周辺のコードを関係するコントローラ、ビュー、コーヒースクリプトに書いていきました。その後、この現象が起こりました。

いつものバグでは、コードにエラーがあってうまく機能しない時はエラーページが表示されてメッセージが出ます。今回は、読み込み中のマークがいつまでも消えないだけでページは表示されているので、どの箇所に誤りがあるのか特定できません。

お願いします。

Comment: RoRはよく知らないですが、その回転マークというのは、モーションGIFとかではないのでしょうか。なにかやっているからクルクル回っているわけではなくて、なにもしないといつまでも回っているものが見えていて、読み込み処理が終わったことを伝える手続が抜けているように思いますが。

Comment: 最近のブラウザは通常エラーログや開発者ツール(IEならF12)を内蔵しているので、エラーの有無や通信状態を確認してみて下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最近のブラウザには開発者向けのツールが付属しています。

たとえば僕がよく使うChromeだと以下のように、デベロッパーツールのネットワークタブでどんなファイルが読み込み中なのか、もしくは読み込まれたのかを確認できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

まずはこういったツールを使って、原因が何なのか（どのファイルが完了待ちになっているのか）を特定してください。

原因を特定したのち、その原因を追記してもらうと、より具体的な回答が得られると思います。

Chromeデベロッパーツールの使い方についてはネット上にたくさん情報が載っています。  
たとえば、こちらのサイトを読んだりすると役に立つかもしれません。

http://www.buildinsider.net/web/chromedevtools/01

なお、こういったツールのバージョンアップは結構激しいので、比較的新しい記事を参照することをオススメします。