# ActionController::Liveとjavascriptがうまく働かない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

初心者です。RoRでチャットを作っています。下記のコードで走らせても思ったように動きません。どこに問題がありますか？

ユーザーの新規のpostを1秒ごとに取得して、render_to_stringした後で送信しています。クライアント側では、それをpostが表示される"post-list"にappendしています。しかし、ユーザーがpostを作成しても、作成は成功しますが、表示がされません。

**chats.coffee**

```
$ ->
  chat_id = $("chat_id").text()
  eventSource = new EventSource(chat_id+"/stream")
  eventSource.addEventListener 'push', (event) ->
    post = event.data
    $('#post-list').append(post)
```

**chats.controller.rb**

```
include ActionController::Live
def stream
  @chat = Chat.find(params[:id])
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  start = Time.zone.now
  loop do
    Post.uncached do
      Post.where('created_at > ?', start).where('chat_id = ?', @chat.id).each do |post|
        html = render_to_string partial:'shared/_post.html.erb', object:post
        response.stream.write("event:push\n")
        response.stream.write("data:#{html}\n\n")
        start = post.created_at
      end
    end 
    sleep 1
  end
  rescue
  ensure
    response.stream.close
end
```

お願いします。

Comment: 僕の代わりにデバッグしてください、というサイトであってはならないと思います

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionController::Live`は使ったことがないのですが、「ActionController::Live render render_to_string」というキーワードでネットを検索したところ、`render_to_string`がそのままでは使えないのでモンキーパッチを当てた、という記事がありました。

http://blog.sorah.jp/2013/07/28/render_to_string-in-ac-live

http://diary.sorah.jp/2013/07/28/render-to-string-actioncontroller-live

```
# モンキーパッチのコード
def render_to_string(*)
  orig_stream = response.stream
  super
ensure
  if orig_stream
    response.instance_variable_set(:@stream, orig_stream)
  end
end
```

ただ、ちょっと情報が古いので最新のRailsではどうなっているのかよくわからないのと、以下のように「結局JS側はうまく動かない」という情報もあったりします。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858470/actioncontrollerlive-with-sse-not-working-properly

ですが、いずれにせよ「作成は成功しますが、表示がされません」だけだと回答する側も原因を予測しづらいです。
なのでChrome デベロッパーツールの「ネットワーク」タブやJavaScriptのデバッグ実行などを使って、正常な実行を妨げている箇所を絞り込んだ後に、その情報と一緒に質問を投げるのがベターだと思います。

デベロッパーツールに関する参考情報: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/6898/85

ちなみにコントローラーのコードで

```
rescue
ensure
  response.stream.close
```

と書いていますが、`rescue`する場合は「発生が予想されるエラーのみ」に絞り込んでおいた方が良いです。

```
# See http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html
rescue IOError
  # When the client disconnects, we'll get an IOError on write
ensure
  response.stream.close
```

現状のコードだとあらゆるエラーを握りつぶしてしまうので、問題が起きていても気づけなくなります。